# Best practice for adding new UI elements to existing views

Tags: wpf

If I have a simple view released in a library and I want a developer to be able to say add additional user interface elements to the view and interact with them , how would I do that? I have done a lot of searching but have not seen anything obvious.

Thanks

Comment: I'll try to give a more concrete example: say my view just has an OK button. Someone inheriting the view whats to add a label, text input field and a cancel button to the view and wire up the behaviors. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you follow existing patterns from the libraries?  E.g.:

If your view is a layout panel, what does WPF do for your content in a layout panel? (Try being a panel)

If your view hosts customer, arbitrary content, what does a WPF custom content host do? (Try hosting a content control)

Etc etc.

(The question isn't very specific, so it's difficult to give a less general answer)

Comment: What I mean is if a customer wants to add their own text field and button and respond to the button to the view I supplied them from my library, how would they go about it?

Comment: @Sam You are still not very clear here. This sentence only tells us the user would make their own text field, as well as a button. It never tells us how it has anything to do with your library.